There is a problem with the booking, does not go to booking_confirmation
I have a form in my app and when i submit it, everything goes correct but it only goes to .../bookings and not .../bookings/booking_conifrmation.html. Here are the views.py and urls.py
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from datetime import timedelta
from .forms import BookingForm
from .models import Booking
from blog.models import Car
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_date
import requests
from .models import BusyDate
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

def booking_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            car_id = form.cleaned_data['car'].id
            start_date = form.cleaned_data['period_start']
            end_date = form.cleaned_data['period_end']
            busy_date = BusyDate(car_id=car_id, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
            #booking = Booking(car_id=car_id, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
            busy_date.save()

            messages.success(request, "Your booking has been successfully submitted.")
            return redirect(reverse('booking_confirmation', kwargs={'car_id': car_id}))
        else:
            for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                    messages.error(request, f"Error in {field}: {error}")
    else:
        # Set default values for period_start and period_end
        start_time = timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        end_time = (timezone.now().date()  + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        initial_data = {'period_start': start_time, 'period_end': end_time}
        form = BookingForm(initial=initial_data)
        
        # Retrieve unavailable dates for selected car
        car_id = request.GET.get('car_id')  # Assuming the car_id is passed in the request
        if car_id:
            try:
                car = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
                start_date = timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                end_date = (timezone.now().date()  + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                response = requests.get(
                    reverse('get_unavailable_dates', args=[car_id]),
                    params={'start_date': start_date, 'end_date': end_date}
                )
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    unavailable_dates_str = response.text.split('\n')
                    unavailable_dates = [parse_date(date_str) for date_str in unavailable_dates_str]
                    form.fields['period_start'].unavailable_dates = unavailable_dates
                    form.fields['period_end'].unavailable_dates = unavailable_dates
                else:
                    messages.error(request, "Failed to retrieve unavailable dates.")
            except Car.DoesNotExist:
                messages.error(request, "Car not found.")
    return render(request, 'bookings/booking_form.html', {'form': form})

def booking_confirmation(request, car_id):
    try:
        latest_booking = Booking.objects.latest('id')
        return render(request, 'bookings/booking_confirmation.html', {'booking': latest_booking})
    except Booking.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, "No bookings found.")
        return redirect('booking_form')

urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import booking_form
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', booking_form, name='booking_form'),
    path('booking/confirmation/<int:car_id>/', views.booking_confirmation, name='booking_confirmation'),
    path('unavailable-dates/<int:car_id>/', views.get_unavailable_dates, name='unavailable_dates'),
    

]

I tried to do something with kwargs and add a new argument to the booking_confirmation function but the same error pops up always
